# How can I open another command line application in Linux from a Java program?

Tags: java, linux, command-line-interface

I'm trying to write a small Java command-line application that will create a new file, and then open it with the systems default editor stored in $EDITOR, and then exit after the editor is closed.

So far, without luck, I've tried the following:

```
Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
dt.edit(file);
```

This method resulted in an `UnsupportedOperationException`, which sort of makes sense as I'm running my program from the terminal, not as a Java appliacation from the desktop.

Right now, I have this:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec(commandString); // "vim newfile"
proc.waitFor();
```

This *is* working, but not how I need it to. When I run

```
ps a | grep vim
```

I can see that it is indeed running in the background, with the filename I've given it:

```
1000 pts/1    S+     0:00 vim 2014-07-16.23-02
```

Any ideas on how to make this run in the foreground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vim, like many interactive programs, expects its `stdin` to be a real terminal that it can send `ioctl` calls to. But when executing through `Runtime.exec()` `stdin` will be redirected to the parent process (see the [Javadoc on `Process` for more information](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html)).

In Java 7, you should be able to use [`ProcessBuilder.inheritIO()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO%28%29) to pass along the file handles. (Disclaimer: I haven't tried it, YMMV.)

Comment: I was hoping to find a Java 6 solution, but it looks like Java 7 is necessary to make this work.

Comment: @grimetime: if you're stuck on Java 6, you could always use JNI to do a `fork()` in native code. Of course, then you have to deal with the pain of pulling in a platform-specific JNI dependency.